# net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE in Chrome after update, but never before, SSL is secure

Tags: ajax, django, google-chrome, ssl

I know this is currently a frequent question but I haven't found anything addresing my version of it. I am sending ajax GET request to a django server that runs on C9 IDE and they are getting canceled since the last Chrome update to v56. I have always closely monitored js errors, there never has been one like it. When i checked my SSL on SSL Labs it's everything green and secure. In Chrome Security the page is marked as Secure with Valid certificate, Secured Resources but with obsolete connection settings:

```
The connection to this site uses a strong protocol (TLS 1.2), a strong key
exchange (ECDHE_RSA with P-256), and an obsolete cipher (AES_256_CBC with 
HMAC-SHA1).
```

This is the only vulnerability that I found, could this be the reason why my ajax request get canceled? If so, how do I fix this? Or perhaps, do I miss something? This is not my area of expertise at all ...

EDIT: As pointed out, this is probably not an issue with the cipher. And as I really don't know what else changed in the last couple of days (besides the chrome update), I am including the whole process:

This is my ajax call:

```
function quote(post_id) {
    AjaxSetup();
        var targetUrl = main_url+'url/url/'+post_id+'/url/';
    }
    var currentRequest = null;
            return currentRequest = $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: targetUrl,
                data: {},
                async:  true,
                timeout: 15000,
                success: function(data){
                    //processing
                }, 

                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Loading seems to have encoutered an error. Please try again.');
                }
            }
            );
}
```

The AjaxSetup function is a standard function that I copied from the django docs:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        console.log(document.cookie.split(';'));
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
            break;
        }
    }
}
return cookieValue;
}
function AjaxSetup() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ 
         beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
             //console.log('AjaxSetup');
             if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
                 // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
                 xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
             }
         }
    });
}
```

This is the view that responds to the call:

```
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def quote_post(request,post_id):
    '''Quote for markitup'''
    post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    data = '<blockquote> '+post.creator.username+' writes<br>\r\n'+post.body+'<br>\r\n</blockquote><br>\r\n'
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='text/html; charset=utf-8')
```

This is the security related part of my settings.py:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*',]
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ('mypageurl',)
CORS_ORIGIN_REGEX_WHITELIST = (
r'^(https?://)?mypageurl',
r'^(https?://)?0.0.0.0:8080',)
```

The rest is pretty much standard django 1.8.5 setup, clicjacking, cors, csrf middleware ...

Comment: I'm sure that a ajax only problem of the site is not caused by obsolete cipher. Unfortunately the question is missing any information which might point to other problems or which might be useful to reproduce the problem. And without this I doubt one can help.

Comment: I know but I really don't know what to add, what code to show. This worked perfectly couple of days ago, if the issue isn't the cipher, I have no clue what else it could be. I guess I have to show all js, settings, views ... and hope somebody readsthrough it.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich: I did some updates but relly have no idea where the issue is and if i added the relevant parts.

Comment: While these are more information there are not enough for somebody else to reproduce the problem. If the site is public it would be helpful to publish the URL and give instructions how to reproduce the problem. Apart from that: since the Ajax call is failing and you seem to use cross origin Ajax you need to check the certificate for the URL targeted by the Ajax call and not the certificate from the site which originates the call.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich: It's the same page, cors was included for a part that used react and requested that. I added the url.

Comment: I just realised registration is required to access the features that are broken ... and registration is not currently working without admin rights ... So, it's useless to add the url. Anyway, thanks for your help.